# what evidence suggests that PIE was a tone language?

Tags: proto-indo-european

I have heard this claim stated with confidence, but it's difficult to see how it could be deduced from traditional reconstruction. Same question for ancient Greek.

Comment: Along the lines, PIE was not a unite language. It well may be that some territories spoke tonal or tone-aspected "accent" of what we call "PIE".

Comment: Ancient Greek wasn't a tone language, but a [pitch accent language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_accent); likewise Vedic Sanskrit. On the basis of these languages, plus additional evidence from other branches (e.g. Balto-Slavic), PIE is reconstructed as a pitch-accent language.

Comment: I approve of TKR's comment, but I do not approve of the linked wikipedia article. By including Korean and Shanghaiese the article has blurred the distinction between pitch accent and tone.

Comment: @TKR true but can we treat pitch-accent as a weaker form of tonal? I mean there are still tones.